# Objective C: Do I have to import arc4random ( )?

Tags: objective-c, arc4random, implicit-declaration

I'm trying to generate a random number between 0 and 3 by saying

```
int i = arc4Random() % 3;
```

but it keeps giving me the warning "implicit declaration of function 'arc4Random' is invalid in c99

Comment: Doesn't have a capital 'r'

Comment: Are you sure you have objective-C and not C?

Comment: @Deduplicator shouldn't matter - in this case its a capitalization issue.

Comment: @Mike: That does not change the fact that the question should be corrected, as it won't be deleted forthwith.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the question. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the capital *r*

```
int i = arc4random() % 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a capital "R" in `arc4Random`. Should be: `int i = arc4random % 3;`.